# Выдает ошибку при нажатии кнопки на jsp странице

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Всем привет. Делаю приложение с использованием maven/tomcat/jdbc. Уже есть основная jsp страница (index.jsp). На ней есть кнопка которая ведет на другую jsp страницу с формой для регистрации. После заполнения формы и нажатия кнопки вылетает ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

никак не могу понять в чем проблема. Подскажите плз в какую сторону мне копать.

```
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>preproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

это мой помник

```
 @WebServlet("/create")
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nameUser = req.getParameter("name");
        String loginUser = req.getParameter("login");
        String passwordUser = req.getParameter("password");

        UserService userService = new UserService();

        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        User user1 = new User(nameUser, loginUser, passwordUser);

        boolean result = false;
        try {
            result = userService.addUser(user1);
        } catch (DBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

это мой сервлет (doget немного криво вставился, но он не важен тут насколько я понимаю)

```
 <head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="/preproject1_war_exploded/create">


        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="text" name="login"/>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Добавить пользователя">
    </form>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

это страничка

Comment: проблемо в конфигурации с базой `MySQL`. Перепроверьте `driver`, `username`, `password`, `host`.

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. Добавил строчку append("serverTimezone=UTC"); в конфигурацию.